# How to prevent TCP network flood triggered by KVM VPS clients?

Tags: tcp, flooding

How to to protect nodes/ detect and block KVM VPS clients that TCP flood the network ?

I use SolusVM VPS management system.

Recently one abuser toke several VPSs and flood it the datacenter network. Luckily I manually found him but I need some automatic solution.

I need something to set a PPS value 15k packets per second, run the script under a cron which checks every VPS packets per second - if it matches that value or exceed it shuts off the VPS and emails me with the date/time - vpsid - packet count. Does anyone have similar script ?

Comment: Try to use iptables or/and fail2ban.

Comment: fail2ban can't do that, what iptable rule will do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Enable some logging client traffic, example iptables log, count tcp connects from each client with fail2ban, block bad guys with iptables rules.

Another way, I think, you can use the connlimit modules which allows you to restrict the number of parallel TCP connections.